# UIScrollView constraints not work

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a scrollview that contains all views in the view controller.I set constrains to all views and it works when phone orientation is Portrait.but when it changes to landscape scrollviews traling constraints not work . here is what happens in landscape mode :

[image]

Comment: How you set the width of it

Comment: You have to specity width of the content, trailing will not work in UIScrollView, for example:
ViewController.View
 >UIScrollView
 >>ContentView (add a constraint ContentView.width=ViewController.View.width)

Comment: @Sh_Khan Yes I set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the problem is that the width of the conetnt view is not flexible , so control drag from the contentView of the scrollView to the main outer view , and select **Equal-widths**

Comment: I dont have contentview but I add all views in a view as a contentview and add it  to scrolview.it has width constraint

Comment: yes, i mean this container view , control-drag from it to the top outer view and select Equal-widths